# Input from the console in java

Tags: java, arrays

I know this is a basic question but I have been trying hard to find Which method I can use if I have to take `2 {123,456}` as the input from console where 2 is the number of inputs to the array and {123,456} are inputs to the array. Should I be using Regex for this since it has { symbols or can it be done by scanner alone??

Comment: surely it can be done, but what have you tried? where is your code?

Comment: You can just [set the delimiter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter-java.lang.String-) of your `Scanner` and then read in the three `int`s.

Comment: @kyla I haven't tried it dude I just wanted to know which methods I can use so that i can try it

Comment: is it necessary to read array input with curly braces?

Comment: @abhishekbafna yes that was  an interview question I had yesterday :-)

Comment: Thats the problem with this website. You guys don't encourage beginners to learn. I don't understand whats wrong with my question why do you guys keep downvoting it. Now I will not be able to ask questions again. :(

Comment: @ajaykumar Now you have got two answer, you should have courtesy to respond back.

Comment: @abhishekbafna now mustafa gave me another -1 because i chose your answer. Is that fair??

Comment: @ajaykumar Answer which which helped you better, you should select that. You can select only one answer.

Comment: @ajaykumar It is community of free people. You should not worry about it. Just keep the good work up. You also start giving back to the community, however way you like.

Comment: Even i have another account with a better reputation I will downvote all this asses. Thats called giving back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the array part as `String` and then strip the `curly braces` using `substring`. Convert the `String` to `int` and store into an array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadArray {    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = read.nextInt();
    String arrayLine = read.next();
    int array[] = new int[count];

    String elements[] = arrayLine.split(",");
    elements[0] = elements[0].substring(1);
    elements[count-1] = elements[count-1].substring(0, elements[count-1].length()-1);
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
      array[i] = Integer.parseInt(elements[i]);
    }

    for (int i : array) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```

**Input :**
2 {123,456}

**Output :**
123
456

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.. But I am not getting any output when i am running it on eclipse. I gave the above input as program arguments while running.

Comment: @ajaykumar Not as program argument, you need to pass them as system input. `Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: how can i do it on eclipse??

Comment: Hey, I don't use eclipse. Can you try on command prompt. `javac ReadArray.java` then run `java ReadArray`. Then it will wait for input, pass it that time.

Comment: just came to know that we can give input in eclipse in the console below.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have read the input as a string, you can do the following:

```
String[] inputs = input.split(" ");
int arrayLength = Integer.parseInt(inputs[0]);
String inputStringData = inputs[1].substring(1, inputs[1].length());
String[] arrayElements = inputStringData.split(",");

int[] array = new int[arrayLength];

for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
  array[i] = Integer.parseInt(arrayElements[i]);
}
```